# How to change the reference location point of a control in C#

Tags: c#, forms, reference, location, controls

In a Windows Form the control location is defined by default as the distance of the left and top corners of the container to the left and top corner of the control, respectively. Thus, when the container has its width or height changed, the control does not move in relation to the left and top corner of the container.
I would like to change the reference point from left and top to right and bottom, so that the control moves when the width and height of the container are changed. Is it possible? How to do so? Some sample code would be great.

Comment: You can do it with some math pretty easily for a single control, but it very quickly becomes quite onerous for multiple controls.  Potentially, you could subclass a form and add the necessary math to move and size all of the controls.  A better choice is to use WPF, which is already designed to provide this kind of scaling.

Comment: If you want the control to be positioned relative to the right or bottom edge, look at the `Anchor` property.